# Decrease Size of Primevue Calendar

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I am using PrimeVue 3.15 in Vue 3.2
PrimeVue popup Calendar takes its input width.(Image 1)
How Can I make it smaller without decreasing the size of the input as in the second image?
I tried all the props related to classes and styles but in vain.

```
<Calendar
   id="paid-on"
   dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
   placeholder="yy-mm-dd"
   v-model="v$.paid_on.$model"
   :manualInput="false"
   :showIcon="true"
   @date-select="onDateChanged"
   />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this property solved my problem

```
panelClass="min-w-min w-10rem"
```

Knowing that min-w-min => `min-width: min-content;`
and w-10rem => `width: 10rem;` as per to primeflex.